# Excel: Create a list (without spaces or blanks) from column of values

Tags: excel, list, checkbox

I have a checklist where if the user responds "yes" or "no", they will get a form or specific directions in column G.

I would like to compile a list of all the forms needed (either in a separate column or below the checklist in column G) when they are done using the checklist. It would be nice if that list did not include blanks. So if items 1-3 and 5 are checked off, it would read like this (in column I4:I7, for instance):

```
Form 1
Form 2
Form 3 
Form 5
```

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7wmE.jpg)

Comment: You can link your check box to a cell where it will output TRUE/FALSE if its checked or not. You can then write a formula using some simple conditional that would output. Please give this a try and if you have any specific issues with your code we would be happy to assist. Remember that SO is not a code writing forum but rather to get pointed assistance regarding specific issues. Regards,

Comment: Edit: If the items are checked off, then the forms will appear (the last item in my image has a form whether it's checked off or not). I have code for that already and don't need assistance there. What I am looking for is something that collects everything in column G and relists it all together. Using "if statements" would get tedious since there are 50+ items. And because the whole point is to show the forms without all the spacing (that way, the user doesn't have to go through the whole checklist), dragging down the formula wouldn't help.

Answer (score 3):

You can get to the point of having column D (using checkbox linking and IF(condition,Form_x,"") and seeing the comments I believe it is not a problem for you).

To get column E you need to select E1:E5 and paste the formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D2:D6,SMALL(IF(D2:D6<>"",ROW(D2:D6)-ROW(D1)),ROW()-ROW(D1))),"")
```

and confirm it with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. The references used are from my example, not your project.

[image]